# "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]" error while rendering partial from another folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, render, partial-views

I have a partial in app/views/school/teachers/_sub_tabs.html.haml file. I rendered this partial in app/views/school/teachers/form.html.haml and it works perfectly. But when I try to render it in components/student/app/views/subjects/students/index.html.haml, it gives error :
`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"school/teachers", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

Error:

```
#tertiary-slider.pills-container

  %span

#tertiary-slider.pills-container
  %span
    = link_to t('.add_names'), teachers_path(@teacher), class: selected_tab[:add_names]
  %span
    = link_to t('.add_subject'),subjects_student_path(@resource), class: selected_tab[:add_subject]
```

It is giving error at line "add_names" tab

1. `app/views/school/teachers/_sub_tabs.html.haml` :

```
#tertiary-slider.pills-container
  %span
    = link_to t('.add_names'), teacher_path(@teacher), class: selected_tab[:add_names]
  %span
    = link_to t('.add_subject'),subjects_student_path(@resource), class: selected_tab[:add_subject]
```

Here the `@resource` could be either `teacher` or `student`.

2. `components/student/app/views/subjects/students/index.html.haml`:

```
.col-xs-12.well-bordered
  = render 'school/teachers/sub_tabs', { selected_tab: { setting: 'selected' } }
```

I think it cannot find the `@teacher` in `subject/students`. But I have return the action in `Subjects::Students` controller as:

```
    def find_resource
      @resource = if params[:teacher_id]
        teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
      else
        @student
      end
    end
```

Routes are as:

```
    scope '/school' do
      resources :teachers, module: :school
      namespace :subjects do
        resources :students
      end
    end
```

When I inspected, the resource passed is `student` and not `teacher`. How to pass `teacher` object? `Names`  and `Subjects` both belongs to `teacher`.

Thanks

EDIT 1:

I tried to pass the `@teacher` object in the path as:

```
#tertiary-slider.pills-container

  %span

#tertiary-slider.pills-container
  %span
    = link_to t('.add_names'), teachers_path(@teacher), class: selected_tab[:add_names]
  %span
    = link_to t('.add_subject'),subjects_student_path(@teacher), class: selected_tab[:add_subject]
```

But even then the teacher is going nil in `Subjects::Students` controller. And the error now I get is:

```
Not found
```

Answer (score 1):

In your partial you have `@teacher` but in your controller you're just assigning the variable to `teacher`. Add the `@`!

EDIT: Also, when you render the partial you can pass `@teachers` through like so:
`= render 'school/teachers/sub_tabs', { teachers: @teachers, selected_tab: { setting: 'selected' } }`
In the partial you can access it with `teachers` then.

Comment: Tried that.. I even tried to pass `Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])`. I think the issue is that teacher object is not getting passed. Any idea how to pass object to index_path?

Comment: Ah yes, so when you render the partial you can add it like so:
`= render 'school/teachers/sub_tabs', { teachers: @teachers, selected_tab: { setting: 'selected' } }`
In the partial you can access it with `teachers` then.
I update my answer.

Comment: Nope, I tried this but it gave the same error as mentioned in the question :(

Comment: Did you adjust the link then?
If you pass the teacher in the render like so: `teacher: @teacher` then in the partial you can use the variable `teacher`. 
So change the render to `@teacher:@teacher` so in the partial @teacher is available (which you then pass to the link_to)

Comment: Could you please elaborate the answer? This is what I did:

In `index.html.haml`, I rendered as
`= render 'school/teachers/sub_tabs', { teacher: @teacher, selected_tab: { setting: 'selected' } }`

And then in `_sub_tabs` partial, used the link as:
`subjects_student_path(@teacher)`

But then it showed "Not found" on the page and url of this page was
`/subjects/student.1`

Comment: Sure, if you render the partial like so: `render 'school/teachers/sub_tabs', { @teacher: @teacher, selected_tab: { setting: 'selected' } }` that means to the partial you give the variable `@teacher` with the value @teacher (which you assign in the controller). So try to render with `@teacher: @teacher`
Is `not found` the whole error you get?

Comment: Yea thats the only error on the page. And in server `Rest query:{}
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 75ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 28.6ms)
` is the error i get

Comment: Is something about nested routes?

Comment: No, I think a 406 might be from the path which you render the partial from? `render 'school/teachers/sub_tabs'...`

Comment: Yes the error is coming from the partial saying the  `add_names` , `require the keys`. But here I have passed the @teacher in the path `teacher_path` but still it showing the error for that path when I try to access the `add_subjects` tab. The tab `add_names` works fine when I try to access the `add_names` tab

Comment: well I guess it's either the path how you render the partial, since it's in the `school/teachers/sub_tabs` - so put it in the shared folder in the views and see what happens, or the variable you pass with the partial. You can try to pass the `@teacher: @teacher` outside the curly braces.
Do you have your project public somewhere? I can have a look there too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188504/discussion-between-moriarty-and-clara).

Comment: could you find an answer?

Comment: Yes, there was issue with routing. Also in the 'selected_tab' was going nil. Therefore changed to '@selected_tab'. It solved the issue. Thanks for your help btw :)